# Want to preserve shared photostream for subscribers but erase everything on my device

Tags: ipad, icloud, sharing, ipados, photo-stream

can one transfer the ownership of a photostream to another user/subscriber? I need to get rid of the contents of a shared photo stream on my device but I am its owner. The subscribers will still need it. I would like to keep the comments, photos and the public page alive but simply give the ownership over to someone else. A simple thing but I cannot seem to figure out how to do that on iOS.
If I erase everything on my iPad Mini in order to sell it will the Shared Photostream also get destroyed? I'm trying to avoid that and hand it over to someone else. Also, should I use the same Apple ID on another device, if I would not want that stream to reappear.

Answer (score 1):

Do not worry about wiping your device to sell it. Shared Photostream is entirely in iCloud and tied to your Apple ID. Wiping your device does not change the status of anything in the cloud. I have wiped devices at various times and signed into various devices - always to have the correct Shared Photostreams appear - ones that others have shared with me and ones I have created myself.

Aside from that, your question is complicated. I am sure that there is no way to transfer ownership of the iCloud Photostream. Your subscribers will have to either save all the pictures to their devices or one could select all of them and create a new Shared Photostream. However, *all* of your comments and likes will be lost during that transition.

Regarding your Apple ID, I certainly recommend you **do not** change Apple ID. However, if you do not have any iTunes, App Store, or iBook Store, and don't mind changing it, I suppose it would be an option. However, I believe there are better ways. I have observed others dealing with multiple Apple IDs and it can be a terrible frustration.

So again, wiping your device is certainly not a big deal, and don't change Apple IDs. Sign back in with your same Apple ID on your new iOS device (if iCloud backup was on) and all your pictures, settings, apps, and documents should automatically come back.